# Require login at start for the Silverlight Business App Template?

Tags: silverlight, authentication

I'd like my Silverlight Business Template app to require the user to login before they can access any of the pages (no anonymous users).

It seems like this should/would be a simple thing.

Anybody?

Thanks

NOTE: I'm pretty new to silverlight and the business template, if there is a 'normal' way of locking down a silverlight app like I'm used in in .aspx (in the web.config ) that would be help too.

* Almost the Answer ***

I think I answered my own question.

I use this on the pages that I don't want anonymous access to.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (!WebContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        LoginRegistrationWindow login = new LoginRegistrationWindow();
        login.Show();
        Uri uri = new Uri("/Home", UriKind.Relative);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that 'almost' fixed my problem.  If the user cancels the LoginForm window, the page is sitting there waiting for the user.  I guess I need to look deeper into this.  Still need help if somebody knows the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this great 3 part tutorial on Mattias Fagerlund's Coding Blog that answered ALL my questions and a few extra

Silverlight pages that Require login
http://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/silverlight-pages-that-require-login-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (!WebContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        LoginRegistrationWindow login = new LoginRegistrationWindow();
       DialogResult dlg= login.Show();
        if (dlg.Cancel)
        {
         Uri uri = new Uri("/Home", UriKind.Relative);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
        }

    }
}
```

ok...used wrong verbage but I was at home and didnt have access to my code...

```
Views.LoginForm login = new Views.LoginForm();

                login.Closed += (s, e2) =>
                {
                    if (login.DialogResult == true)
                    {
                        ContentFrame.Content = null;
                        Views.PrimarySearchView view = new Views.PrimarySearchView();
                        ContentFrame.Content = view;
                        Wait.End();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ContentFrame.Content = null;
                    }
                };
                login.Show();
```

this assumes that LoginRegistrationWindow is a ChildWindow

You should be able to get the gist of it from my sample now.

Comment: Unfortunately with this being a Silverlight App, I can't add a reference to a WPF assembly to make use of DialogResult.  Thanks though